# How do I get a simple tree of files to concat using broccoli.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to get my head around [broccoli.js](https://github.com/joliss/broccoli) but am running into an error. If you look in my [GitHub](https://github.com/cullymason/ember-broccoli-starter-kit) repo, you will see that I have a brocfile.js that looks like this:

**brocfile.js**

```
var compileES6 = require('broccoli-es6-concatenator')
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees')


var app = 'app'
app = pickFiles(app,{
    srcDir: '/',
    destDir: 'app-kit'
})

var appJS = compileES6(app, {
    inputFiles: ['/app-kit/**/*.js'],
    outputFile: '/dist/app.js'
})

module.exports = mergeTrees([appJS]);
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Built with error:
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'tmp/static_compiler-tmp_dest_dir-JjclDVEm.tmp/undefined'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:684:18)
    at addLegacyFile (/Users/cully/Sites/ember-todo/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/index.js:130:44)
    at /Users/cully/Sites/ember-todo/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/index.js:47:5
    at invokeCallback (/Users/cully/Sites/ember-todo/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/promise.js:228:21)
    at publish (/Users/cully/Sites/ember-todo/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/promise.js:176:9)
    at publishFulfillment (/Users/cully/Sites/ember-todo/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/promise.js:312:5)
    at flush (/Users/cully/Sites/ember-todo/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/asap.js:41:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

In the long run I would like to use this as a starting point for building ember.js apps so I created a [github repo](https://github.com/cullymason/ember-broccoli-starter-kit). If you go there you can see my file structure. Any thoughts on why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 4):

I've been wrestling with Broccoli myself for the last few days. It's new to me as well, but I cloned your repo and got `broccoli serve` to work by doing the following:

1) I created a "loader.js" file at `loader/loader.js`. The loader.js file contains ES6 Module Loader polyfill code to allow ES6 modules to load in non-ES6 browsers. I grabbed the file from the Broccoli sample app: https://github.com/joliss/broccoli-sample-app/blob/master/vendor/loader.js

2) I injected the loader into the app tree and referenced it in the `compileES6` config. (This option was the `undefined` value in your error.)

Here's the updated `brocfile.js` that successfully builds for me.

```
//brocfile.js

var compileES6 = require('broccoli-es6-concatenator');
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');


var app = 'app';
app = pickFiles(app,{
  srcDir: '/',
  destDir: 'app-kit'
});

// Reference to ES6 loader
var loader = "loader";

// Squash the loader and app trees into one
var sourceTrees = [app, loader];
sourceTrees = new mergeTrees(sourceTrees);

var appJS = compileES6(sourceTrees, {
  loaderFile: 'loader.js', // This required option was undefined before
  inputFiles: ['app-kit/**/*.js'],
  outputFile: '/dist/app.js'
});

module.exports = mergeTrees([appJS]);
```

I hope that helps you get to the next step on your Broccoli adventure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [broccoli-concat](https://github.com/rlivsey/broccoli-concat), then:

```
 emberTests = concatFilter(emberTests, {inputFiles: ['**/*.js'], outputFile:'/tests.js'});
 templates  = concatFilter(templates, {inputFiles: ['**/*.handlebars'], outputFile:'/templates.js'});
 trees      = concatFilter(trees, {inputFiles: ['**/*.js'], outputFile:'/app.js'});
```